# Running an inner and an outer joins

Tags: node.js, mongodb, join, mongoose

I have 3 collections with each having a different set of information:

- offers
- providers
- userpreferences

Offers and Providers can be joined using provider_id:

```
 const aggregate = Offers.aggregate();
 aggregate.lookup({
   from: 'providers'
   localField: 'provider_id',
   foreignField: 'provider_id',
   as: 'providers'
 });
 aggregate.unwind({
   path: '$providers'
 });
```

There's a one-to-one relationship between offers and providers (i.e I am guaranteed to find a provider for every offer).

I also need to determine whether any of these offers were 'liked' by the user.

Right now when I create a second look-up call only the offers that were liked by the user are returned, instead of all of the offers, whether they were liked by the user or not. Not all offers would have a record (record_id === offer_id && record_type === 'offer') in the 'userpreferences' collection.

```
aggregate.lookup({
    from: 'userpreferences',
    localField: 'offer_id',
    foreignField: 'record_id',
    as: 'userprefernces'
});
aggregate.unwind({
    path: '$userprefernces',
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
});
aggregate.match({
    'userprefernces.user_id': params.userId,
    'userprefernces.record_type': 'offer'
});
```

Can someone tell me why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I sat in a small group with a MongoDb expert one time. I remember him saying, to avoid aggregates.
What you are trying to do can be done by using the find().toArray() methods on each of the three collections.
Use the find method while matching on an indexed field for each of the collections is better than writing complex aggregates with lookups.

Comment: Ryan thanks for your response. Do you mean to get the user preference and loop through the result set to see if any of offer_ids match the ones in userpreference result set? Is there a clean way to do it in the aggregation pipeline?

Comment: What I am saying is, if you have the necessary ids in your data to do a lookup in an aggregate. You have the info to make three distinct find() calls to mongo and Project any data needed.